# Setting Custom Session in index.php - Problems

Tags: magento-1.9, session, maintenance

Creating a custom session in a store view's index.php in a subdirectory of the main magento installion.

The code I added is as follows:

```
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::init();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setRefer("access");
$refer = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getRefer();
echo $refer;
```

I added the code under **require_once $mageFilename;** in index.php otherwise I would get Mage errors.

I want to use the session for something more complex but I can't get even this basic code to work!

This causes the mantenance page to display for some reason with **access** echod at the top of the page. Maintenance displays even when I take out the code which displays the maintenence page inside the index.php.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

EDIT1:

When moving my code to bottom of file:

```
$mageRunCode = 'mystore';
$mageRunType = 'store';
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setRefer("denied");
$refer = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getRefer();
if($refer == "access") {
}else{
    include_once 'XXXXXXXXX/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

This makes my store view appear and then stacks the maintenance page below it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting it at the bottom of the file. It worked like this for me without the first two lines

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setRefer("access");
$refer = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getRefer();
echo $refer;
```

Re: new problem

Try copying line 64 -

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

to after

```
require_once $mageFilename;
```

and add in the check for the session like -

```
$maintenanceFile = 'path to file';
require_once $mageFilename;
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && $refer != 'access') {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

Fyi - using regular php session variables might be more suitable if you need to do much with them in index.php. The reasons for the errors is because of Mage not being loaded when you try to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when adding this at the bottom I simply get no echo at all

Comment: Try searching the page for 'access' using ctrl+f (windows) or cmd+f (mac). I couldn't see it straight away

Comment: Ok thanks this worked however created another problem!

SEE POST

The code is below where I pull in the store view. So when session "denied" the user should see maintenance. As the store view is loaded first it shows the store view stacked on top of maintenance!

Comment: well feel free to ask but if you could select my answer as correct and upvote if it's fixed the problem in the question i'd appreciate it

Comment: If i put the code above the store view code I get the error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /PATH/app/Mage.php on line 463

Comment: it needs to go at the very bottom so that everything has loaded. It shouldn't really be going in here anyway. There should be a controller or an observer dealing with this really but just in terms of a solution to the question put it at the very end of the file

Comment: Yes but when the store view has loaded and then my session IF statement trys to throw maintenance it simply stacks the maintenance below rather than instead of my stores view

Comment: updated answer!

Comment: Thanks for the update I will give this a go! As for standard PHP sessions I did try that but magento was having issues wih saving them and so they weren't going from page to page which is why I opted for Magentos! Thanks again